# How to add if child section

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

```
return InkWell(
          onTap: () => { if(1==0){
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    ImageScreen(
                      url: widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString(),
                    ),
              ),),
          }},

          child: Image.network(
            widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString(),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,


          )

      );
```

hello all stackoverflow users, ı need help for this. how can i add if here
`child: Image.network(widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString(),fit: BoxFit.cover,`

If you have any other suggestions for me to solve such problems, please do.

Comment: such as if(true){ child: ....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
child: widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString().contains("keyword") ? Image.network(
    widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString(),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ) : SizedBox()
```

here if `condition` be `true`, `Image` would be build, if be `false`, `SizedBox` would be build.

Comment: hello widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString() how can ı check this string contains("keyword")  then with child:

Comment: I updated my answer. check it out @AliK

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
child : conditionTrue ? ImageFromNetowrk : null,
```

OR

```
child : conditionTrue ? ImageFromNetowrk : SizedBox(),
```

Comment: hello widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString() how can ı check this string contains("keyword") then with child: ..

Comment: You can do something like this  widget.userbio.resimler![index].toString().contains("yourKeyWord")